# Problema con asincronismo en Node

Tags: nodejs

soy nuevo en Node... Tengo una modulo que conecta a una BD de postgres por medio de pg-node. En eso no tengo problemas. Mi problema es que al llamar a ese modulo, desde otro modulo, y despues querer usar los datos que salieron de la BD me dice undefined... Estoy casi seguro que es porque la conexion a la BD devuelve una promesa, y los datos no estan disponibles al momento de usarlos. Pego codigo

Modulo de conexion a PG

```
module.exports = function (query) {
const { Client } = require ('pg')

const connection = {
 user: 'postgres',
 host: 'localhost',
 database : 'hoteltest',
 password: '1234',
 port: 5432
}

const client = new Client(connection)

 var datos;

 client.connect()
 client.query(query)
   .then (response => {
     datos = response.rows
     console.log(datos)
     return datos
     client.end()
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log(err)
     client.end()
   })
}
```

y asi llamo a este modulo:

```
import data from './pg/index.js'

var pgdata;
pgdata = data('SELECT * FROM usuarios')

console.log(pgdata)
```

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias!

Comment: Solucionado!!! GRacias. un simple Callback. Estube probando llamar con una promesa, con asyn await, y nada. Solo me funciono con callbaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque lo hayas solucionado, te comento que solo te faltaba retornar la promise del modulo PG, te muestro a lo que me refiero:

```
module.exports = function (query) {
    const { Client } = require ('pg')

    const connection = {......}

    const client = new Client(connection)

   client.connect()

   return client.query(query) //Tienes que devolver la promesa para poder usarla
      .then (response => {
           client.end()

           return response.rows
      })
      .catch(err => {
           client.end()
      })
}
```

Y recuerda que devuelves una promesa, por lo tanto:

```
import data from './pg/index.js'

data('SELECT * FROM usuarios')
    .then(pgdata => { /* lo que necesites realizar */ })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Espero que con este ejemplo te haya ayudado a comprender un poco las Promise, también puedes resolverlo con Async/Await y Promise, busca por internet que encontrar muchos ejemplos, sino pregunta.

Saludos